# WPF Issue with same ALT hotkey

Tags: c#, wpf, access-keys

I have a window with 3 textboxes and labels with following properties:

```
 <Label x:Name="label" Content="_Label" Target="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"/>
 <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label"/>
 <Label x:Name="label2" Content="_Label" Target="{Binding ElementName=textBox2}"/>
```

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7jk7.png)

You can see that "label" and "label2" have the same <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> key but different Target property. When I focus **textBox middle** and I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> I need that textBox2 is focues (like in **MFC**). I can't use code behide because I was made about 200 windows.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should avoid duplicate hotkeys as much as possible... Select another letter as the shortcut. If not possible, the try to update other conflicting shortcut. If still not possible, verify if you can change some label (or maybe append a letter in parenthesis at the end like Label1 (_k)).

Comment: I also think that usually, it would be preferable to have a few controls missing shortcut than having duplicate one. It make the software more predictable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you really need with out `code behind` or `ViewModel` you can do it by adding the same short cut to `Label1` like below,

```
    <Label x:Name="label" Grid.Row="0" Content="_Label" Target="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Grid.Row="1" Content="_Label" Target="{Binding ElementName=textBox1}"/>
    <Label x:Name="label2" Grid.Row="2" Content="_Label" Target="{Binding ElementName=textBox2}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

If you can make a ViewModel then `InputBinding` with `KeyBinding` can make it work.